# Does basil.js run with InDesign Version CS3?

Tags: javascript, basil.js

I downloaded basil.js' bundle and installed it the way the installation guide told me.
But running the example-scripts always fails.

It ist said there: JavaScript Error, Number 24, Line 7, Date.now is no function.

I reinstallend and installed again twice, checking if i connected and named the folders in the right way and everything seems to be ok.

Now I thought that maybe my InDesign-Version is just to old? I still work with CS3. Does anybody know about that?

Thank you
Eva

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are afraid that it looks like CS3 is too old, yes. We support CS5+ officially.

Best wishes,
Ludwig